# How to get ZonedDateTime of "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE" with CreateNativeQuery

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I use createNativeQuery to get data from a postgres Database.
The column "date_time_column" is an "timestamp with time zone".

It's just a simple select.
The Problem is, that the date_time_column in my app gets the datatype `java.sql.Timestamp`. So, the Timezone is gone.

[image]

Because I can't use an Entity class(The select will be created at runtime), I can't define a columnDefinition on the column like [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-java-time):

```
@Column(name = "date_time_column ", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
```

So how can I get the correct data?

Right now I run through the results and cast the column to "ZonedDateTime" but I think this costs a lot of performance and isn't the best approach:

list.map { ((it as Array<Any?>).get(0) as Timestamp).toLocalDateTime().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))}

Comment: PostgreSQL won't store the offset information even the column is `timestamp with time zone`

Comment: Why you think it won't?
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: Use `OffsetDateTime`, not `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: The use of 'LocalDateTime' is just my workaround. I need the data as a datatype with timezone directly out of the database.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return data from table with `UTC` timezone format you can change native query with something like below:

```
@Query(nativeQuery=true,value= "select date_time_colum at time zone 'UTC' from table")
List yourMethod(..);
```

By this way, you know that returned data is in `UTC` format & you can do any operations based on that.

Lets say you want to further change timezone from `UTC` to `AST` then your query will be :

```
@Query(nativeQuery=true,value= "select date_time_colum at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'AST' from table")
    List yourMethod(..);
```

In both cases, Timezone will not be lost as you mentioned in question.

Comment: This is probably a better approch than mine, but this returns still a timestamp where it should return a ZonedDateTime. So at the end i have to map it as well.

Comment: Yeah, it may be little bit difficult to directly return value which will be of type `ZonedDateTime`.